# "07:37 am GMT+5.30 on 10/11/2011" how to convert this string to datetime in python

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, replace

According to the questions, it is been asked to remove the +5.30 from the string:

```
import datetime
b="07:37 am GMT+5.30 on 10/11/2011"
a=b.replace("+5.30","")
print(a)
```

Now, how to covert this string to date using datetime in python?
I tried :

```
c=datetime.datetime("%H:%M %p on %d/%m/%Y")
Print(c)
```

But this didn't work, it shows error.
What to do?

Comment: why remove the GMT offset if you can parse it properly via `datetime.datetime.strptime("07:37 am GMT+5.30 on 10/11/2011".replace('.', ':'), "%I:%M %p %Z%z on %m/%d/%Y")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you may use `strptime` method to convert string into datetime objects.

```
import datetime 
b = "07:37 am GMT+5.30 on 10/11/2011"
a = b.replace("+5.30","")
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%I:%M %p GMT on %d/%m/%Y")
print(a)
```

Comment: I assume there is no different offset since +5.30 is replaced by an empty string. If there is a different offset, I would suggest to use `dateutil` module. I think `%z` can only be used when the time offset is like +0530 after looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: while this may answer the OP's question, I'd add that there is a proper way to handle GMT offsets, see my comment on the question. Such specific solutions tend to bite you some time in the future.

Comment: btw. dateutil's parser will also fail here because of the `.` in `GMT+5.30` - needs to be a colon; `:`.